# Animation on change image css jquery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a social buttons which changes the image on hover. It's working fine

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcmHu/240/)

```
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLGeYXo.png" class="social-icons social-fb "/>
</a>
```

My CSS:

```
.social-fb:hover {
   content:url("http://i.imgur.com/bU0lzac.png");
}
```

But how can I make some animations ot it like when I hover and as the image change, there's an animation. Any animation will do. Thanks!

Comment: Try this http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/

Comment: @ArunKumar I would love to. But I jusy need simple animations and don't want to load an entire css hover scripts. Thanks though

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following css to do a pulse:

```css
.social-fb:hover {
  content: url("http://i.imgur.com/bU0lzac.png");
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
    transform: scale3d(1.05, 1.05, 1.05);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}
.pulse {
  -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
  animation-name: pulse;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/TLGeYXo.png" class="social-icons social-fb " />
</a>

<a href="#">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bU0lzac.png" />
</a>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcmHu/247/)

Comment: Thanks will do :) Will select this as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of different animations you can do, I've created a simple rotating one [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wcmHu/244/)

The trick is to include the transition attribute on the element before defining it's hover state:

```
.social-fb{
    transition: 750ms ease-in-out;
}
```

The `750ms` is the duration of the animation and `ease-in-out` is an easing setting which makes it look smoother and more realistic.

Then set the transform/animation you'd like, here I'm rotating the icon 360 degrees

```
.social-fb:hover {
    content:url("http://i.imgur.com/bU0lzac.png");
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

It's also worth looking at starting to use [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) icons instead of images for things like facebook icons, they're free, scale perfectly, load quicker than images and you can also get the background to fade from to colour to the next, [check out this pen to see an example](http://codepen.io/suth_a/pen/pjRGWP)